presto-thrift-spec: Dependency problems found
My build is failing and here is the full description
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze-only (default) on project presto-thrift-spec: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze-only (default) on project presto-thrift-spec: Dependency problems found
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:195)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Dependency problems found
at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.analyze.AbstractAnalyzeMojo.execute (AbstractAnalyzeMojo.java:253)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:195)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:515)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
I am trying to build presto on my local machine.
